# Speeding up my simple Redis .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, linq, redis

I have started writing an application which i want to use for fast searching through my data.

I started using the client from ServiceStack.Redis. (Got it via NuGet) 
Around this i wrote a little test app to insert 20k of company data records and now i'm querying this thing using the following code:

```
using (var companies = redisClient.As<Company>())
{
  var companiesFound = companies.GetAll().Where(x => x.CompanyName.Contains(searchString));
  dgvOutput.DataSource = companiesFound.ToList<Company>();
}
```

The **Company** class i use looks like this:

```
public class Company
{
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public string CompanyName { get; set; }
  public string CompanyAddress { get; set; }
  public string CompanyCity { get; set; }
}
```

This all works well, but i can't say that it's fast. Can anyone help me on what to do to get this thing running as fast as it can be? Indexes? Different type of queries? Better not use LINQ?

Comment: Did you try to query the Databse directly? 
If yes do you have the same performance problems?
When the query takes a long time then it has nothing to do with your code...

Comment: Yes, i'm quite sure it has something to do with my code. The console app is much faster. So my question is, how do i write a smarter query to do some Redis searching through my company objects.

Comment: Hmm, for me it seems that you are getting all records of company in advance and then filter it:
"companies.GetAll().Where(..."
Do you need the GetAll() call?

Comment: That is where my problem is, i cannot find any manual/reference on how to work with this Redis .NET client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this Documentation:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/IRedisClient
But it' s not an Linq Provider.
I didn't find a way to get companies filtered, you can only get all or one by Id.

So I think, in the beginning, you have to get all Companies. And store it in application cache, maybe on Startup of your application

```
companies =  redisClient.As<Company>().GetAll();
```

and then you can filter the List with Linq2Objects like you did before:

```
var companiesFound = companies.Where(x => x.CompanyName.Contains(searchString));
  dgvOutput.DataSource = companiesFound;
```

I'm not sure if you need the ToList call.

Hopefully someone gives you a better solution.

Comment: I found a good explanation and overview of unsing the redis Client:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/388982/Document-Databases-A-look-at-them